# Prime/paint drywall ceiling in bathroom around ceiling light

Tags: drywall, shower

I'm installing a ceiling in a shower where the contractors left it unfinished. From reading, it sounds like drywall as a shower ceiling can be fine if it's properly primed and painted. Here's my question, though-- the ceiling has a hole cut in it for a light, and that hole obviously has an exposed drywall edge that won't be sealed with the primer or paint. Is that OK, or do I have to somehow get the primer and paint inside the edge of that hole?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a typical exhaust fan in operation, there's no concern. Cut drywall edges around electrical boxes are never treated. It would only be in severe moisture situations that you'd have a problem, and sealing the hole isn't the solution there anyway.